# Django: order_by API json value or cached objects

Tags: json, django, caching

I've got a model method that calculates the score of votes using the HN ranking algorithm in my model that also caches each score. `calculate_score()` is the main thing to focus on here.

```
class Submission(models.Model):
    submission_type = models.CharField(_('Submission Type'),
                                       max_length=255,
                                       choices=tuple([(media.name.lower(), media.value) for media in MediaTypes]),
                                       blank=False)
    title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=100, blank=False)
    url = models.URLField(_('Link'), blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(_('Description'))
    flagged = models.BooleanField(_('Is Flagged for Review'), default=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_submissions')
    thumbnail = models.ImageField()
    date_submitted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    by_votes = VoteCountManager()
    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.submission_type + ': ' + self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('submit_detail', args=[
            str(self.submission_type),
            str(self.id),
        ])

    def get_vote(self):
        """
        Returns the number of votes associated with a particular submission
        :return: int
        """
        return self.submission_votes.count()

    def calculate_score(self):
        """
        This is a variation of the HN ranking algorithm
        :return: score
        """
        secs_in_hour = float(60 * 60)
        g = 1.2

        delta = timezone.now() - self.date_submitted
        item_hour_age = delta.total_seconds() / secs_in_hour
        votes = self.submission_votes.count() - 1
        score = votes / pow((item_hour_age + 2), g)
        cached = cache.get('s{0}'.format(self.pk))
        if not cached:
            cache.set('s{0}'.format(self.pk), score, 30)
        return score
```

I'm using the `djangorestframework` that serializes my model:

```
class SubmissionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    score = serializers.SerializerMethodField('rank')

    class Meta:
        model = Submission

    def rank(self, obj):
        return obj.calculate_score()
```

I have two ways that I think I can solve my problem, but I don't know how to do either of them, and I'm not sure which one is best.  Since I'm caching the `score` for each individual submission.  I was trying to order the submissions in a ListView like this pulling from the cache:

```
class SubmissionList(ListView):
    model = Submission
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(SubmissionHotList, self).get_queryset().annotate(
            score=cache.get('s{0}'.format(x) for x in Submission.pk)
            votes=models.Count('submission_votes'),
        ).order_by(
            '-score', '-votes',
        )
```

But I found that `order_by` only works on the database level, and I would have to create a database field for the calculated score, which I would like to avoid if possible.  My other possibility is using the serialized data in my API for `Submission` in this `ListView`, but I'm not sure if APIs are only there for external applications, or if I could use them in the same application that the API is generated.

I guess my question is.  Would it be better to get the cached objects to list each submission in a particular order, or could I use the API to accomplish this?  And if I used the API, how could I parse and order the JSON data in the ListView, while keeping `votes` as a secondary ordering mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to display all items without pagination, you will not lose any performance if you do something like

```
import operator

class SubmissionList(TemplateView):

    template_name = "submissions.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SubmissionList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        submissions = Submission.objects.all().annotate(
            votes=models.Count('submission_votes')
        )
        sorted_submissions = sorted(submissions, key=lambda x:(cache.get('s{0}'.format(x.pk)), x.votes), reverse=True)
        context['submissions'] = sorted_submissions

        return context
```